# Convert OWIN Web API from http to https

Tags: c#, https, owin

I have OWIN windows from API in http I want to convert it to https. I have change in code from http to https but after ran it I couldnt get any response

The response from POSTMAN

[image]

Code :

```
  static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            string baseAddress = "https://+:81";

            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {

                Console.ReadLine();
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }

        }
    }
```

Any Solutions ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to changing the base address of your API, you also need to install a certificate and configure SSL/TLS using netsh, e.g.:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:81 
  certhash=‎<CERT_THUMBPRINT> appid=<APP_ID>
```

The following blog post outlines the steps that are required in greater detail:

https://opensequence.net/post/113488532197/hosting-an-owin-application-in-windows-using

Comment: Just in case, it didn't work for me, until I used the "magic appid": {12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf}

It seems that HttpListener will listen to HTTPS, only to the app with this appid.